# [React]Module not found: You attempted to import ../../img/photo.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs

I have this problematic error, here is the tree of my project

https://www.noelshack.com/2020-06-7-1581288494-tree.png

and here is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Grid, Cell } from 'react-mdl';
import img from "../../img/photo.jpg";

class Landing extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{width: '100%', margin: 'auto'}}>
                <Grid className="landing-grid">
                    <Cell col={12}>
                        <img src={img} alt="logo"/>
                    </Cell>
                </Grid>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

the image does not display, do you have the solution? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import the assets such as images. Just put them in the public folder and address them using environment variables. For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Grid, Cell } from 'react-mdl';

class Landing extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{width: '100%', margin: 'auto'}}>
                <Grid className="landing-grid">
                    <Cell col={12}>
                        return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/photo.jpg'} />
                    </Cell>
                </Grid>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

**Note:** The `public` folder can be found in the root folder with the name public, ex: `YourAppName/public`. All suggest creating a `static` folder inside it and put all assets on it by type for example `static/img` then your address will be `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/static/img/photo.jpg` .

**PS:** [See React docs about using public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)